# creating json as is shown in Postman

Tags: json, postman

I'm trying to post data via API to InsightVM. I keep getting error 400 which means wrong format. I break it down, the problem is in hostnames part.

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

  if (host_info.getDataType() == dataType.Web_Vulnerability && methodType == MethodType.Add_host_To_Site)
                {
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
                    json2.put("name",host_info.getHost_fqdn());
                    json2.put("source", "Splunk");
                    array.add(json2);

                    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
                    json.put("date",OffsetDateTime.now().format(dtf) );
                    json.put("ip",host_info.getHost_ip());
                    json.put("os",host_info.getOperating_system());
                    json.put("hostNames",array); // problem is here 
                }
```

is the code above provide the same format as below:

```
{

"date": "2019-05-20",
"ip": "00.00.00.00",
"os":"Linux",
"hostNames": 
[
{
"name": "corporate-workstation-1102DC.acme.com",
"source": "Splunk"
}
]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONArray implements Collection.
 
While JSONObject has an overloaded put() method,
which takes a Collection and wraps it in a JSONArray which might be causing the problem.
**Can you try the following -**

```
jsonObject.put("hostNames",(Object)array);
```